# ASP.NET [Date Input]

Tags: asp.net

How to make some Date input control like a texbox.

I need start date and end date and count period and make a database select.
But if I put 2 Calendars on my page that will be looking like wierd :-/
So I want to know how to make some dateinput masks for textboxes or some else solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Default.aspx) offers a couple of ways to do this. Probably the one you want is the [CalendarExtender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) which you attach to a TextBox control, and which displays a clickable calendar when the textbox gets the focus, e.g. this markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="MyCalendar" TargetControlID="TextBox1" />
```

produces this in the browser when the textbox is clicked on:
[alt text http://www.philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/calendarextender.png](http://www.philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/calendarextender.png)

There's also a [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) in [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) that does something similar.

Another extender to look at is the [MaskedEditExtender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) which allows you to limit your user's input so that they can only enter valid dates in a TextBox.